# Change promise type

Tags: typescript, promise

I have a function that should return `Promise<Type1>` and the result is actually obtained by calling another function which returns `Promise<Type2>`. How should I do that? Is the following correct? Thanks,

```
function1():Promise<Type1>{
  return function2().then(result => {...some code that convert the result (Type2) to a Type1 object...});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map from one to another type, you can do it inside the `.then()` callback, as you already did.

But don't forget to change the return type of `function1` when your actual return type should be `Type2`:

```
function1(): Promise<Type2>{
  return function2.then(result => {...some code that convert the result (Type1) to a Type2 object...});
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry that is some typo...